# Unable to record audio from microphone to QFile in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, audio

I am trying to record audio from the default microphone present in my desktop and store it in QFile.
Finally I want to play the recorded file using windows media player. The issue is that QAudioInput has a method bytesReady() which always returns 0 in my case. Even if the audio state is QAudio::ActiveState the bytesReady() shows 0 bytes implying that there are no audio bytes to read from the microphone. The system microphone works just fine. My code gets perfectly compiled, I also get a file in the specifed location with 80KB size, but the file doesn't play with windows media player even if saved as a .wav, it returns an error.
The output window shows bytesReady as 0 in my case everytime. I suspect the QAudioInput is not able to read audio data from microphone.

Could you please help me find mistakes in my code?

```
 `class mikeDemoClass : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        mikeDemoClass(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
        ~mikeDemoClass();

    public slots:

        void startRecording();
        void browseFiles();
        void stopRecording();
        void handleAudioInputState(QAudio::State);
        void notified();

    private:
        Ui::mikeDemoWidget ui;
        QAudioInput *audioInput;
        QFile *recordFile;
        QTimer *testTimer;
        int audio_state;

    };

// cpp file starts here

    #include <QIODevice>
    #include "mic_demo.h"

    mikeDemoClass::mikeDemoClass(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
        : QWidget(parent, flags)
    {
        ui.setupUi(this);
        audioInput = NULL;
        recordFile = NULL;
        audio_state = -1;

        connect(ui.browseButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(browseFiles()));
        connect(ui.recordingButton,SIGNAL(clicked()), this,SLOT(startRecording()));
    }

    mikeDemoClass::~mikeDemoClass()
    {
        if(recordFile)
        {
            delete recordFile;
            recordFile = NULL;
        }
    }

    void mikeDemoClass::browseFiles()
    {
        QString FileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Browse Files"), "D:/", tr("Media Files (*.raw)"));
        if(!FileName.isEmpty())
        {
            recordFile = new QFile(FileName);
            QTextDocument *textDoc = new QTextDocument(FileName);
            ui.textEdit->setDocument(textDoc);
        }

    }

    void mikeDemoClass::startRecording()
    {
        bool status = recordFile->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        if(!status)
        {
            qDebug() <<"Error opening the file";
        }


        QString default_deviceName = "";
        QAudioFormat preferred_format;

        QList<QAudioDeviceInfo> device_list = QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioInput);
        int count = device_list.count();

        if(device_list.empty())
        {
            qDebug() <<"The Audio Input Devices is empty";
        }
        else
        {

        foreach(QAudioDeviceInfo device_info, device_list)
        {
            QString device_name = device_info.deviceName();
            qDebug() << "device_name:" << device_name.toLatin1();
        }

        QAudioDeviceInfo info = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();
        default_deviceName = info.deviceName();

        if(!default_deviceName.isEmpty())
        {
            preferred_format = info.preferredFormat();
            QString codec = preferred_format.codec();
            int sampleRate = preferred_format.sampleRate();
            int sampleSize = preferred_format.sampleSize();
            int channelCount = preferred_format.channelCount();
            int sampleType = preferred_format.sampleType();
            int byteOrder =  preferred_format.byteOrder();
            qDebug() << "codec:" << codec.toLatin1() << "sampleRate :" << sampleRate << "sampleSize:" << sampleSize << "channel Count:" << channelCount << "sample type:" <<sampleType
                << "byteOrder:" << byteOrder;
        }

    }

    QAudioFormat format;
    format.setSampleRate(8000);
    format.setChannels(1);
    format.setSampleSize(8);
    format.setCodec("audio/PCM");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

    QAudioDeviceInfo info = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();
    if(!info.isFormatSupported(format))
    {
        qDebug() <<"Default format not supported, try to use nearest format";
        format = info.nearestFormat(format);
    }

    audioInput = new QAudioInput(info, format, this);

     connect(audioInput, SIGNAL(notify()), this, SLOT(notified()));
    connect(audioInput,SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)),this, SLOT(handleAudioInputState(QAudio::State)));
    QTimer::singleShot(10000, this, SLOT(stopRecording()));

    //audioInput->setBufferSize(4096);
    qDebug() << "platform buffer size:" << audioInput->bufferSize();
    audioInput->start(recordFile);
}

void mikeDemoClass::stopRecording()
{
    testTimer->stop();
    audioInput->stop();
    recordFile->close();
    delete audioInput;
}

void  mikeDemoClass::handleAudioInputState(QAudio::State state)
{
    qDebug() << "Audio State:" << state;

    audio_state = state;

    if(state == QAudio::StoppedState)
    {
        qDebug() << "Error State:" << audioInput->error();

        if(audioInput->error() != QAudio::NoError)
        {
            qDebug() << "QAudioInput error:" << audioInput->error();
        }
    }
}

void  mikeDemoClass::notified()
{
    if(audio_state ==  QAudio::ActiveState)
    {
        qDebug() << "Error State:" << audioInput->error();

        qDebug() << "platform buffer size after calling QAudioInput start():" << audioInput->bufferSize();

        qDebug() << "bytesReady = " << audioInput->bytesReady()
        << ", " << "elapsedUSecs = " <<audioInput->elapsedUSecs()
        << ", " << "processedUSecs = "<<audioInput->processedUSecs();
    }

}`
```

The output displays as follows:

```
   device_name: "Microphone (High Definition Aud" 
device_name: "default" 
codec: "audio/pcm" sampleRate : 11025 sampleSize: 8 channel Count: 1 sample type: 1 byteOrder: 1 
Default format not supported, try to use nearest format 
platform buffer size: 0 
Audio State: 0 
Error State: 0 
platform buffer size after called QAudioInput start(): 1600 
bytesReady =  0 ,  elapsedUSecs =  1003000 ,  processedUSecs =  1000000 
Error State: 0 
platform buffer size after called QAudioInput start(): 1600 
bytesReady =  0 ,  elapsedUSecs =  1998000 ,  processedUSecs =  2000000 
Error State: 0 
platform buffer size after called QAudioInput start(): 1600 
bytesReady =  0 ,  elapsedUSecs =  3003000 ,  processedUSecs =  3000000 
Error State: 0 
platform buffer size after called QAudioInput start(): 1600 
bytesReady =  0 ,  elapsedUSecs =  4000000 ,  processedUSecs =  4000000 
Error State: 0 
platform buffer size after called QAudioInput start(): 1600 
bytesReady =  0 ,  elapsedUSecs =  5006000 ,  processedUSecs =  5000000 
Error State: 0 
platform buffer size after called QAudioInput start(): 1600 
bytesReady =  0 ,  elapsedUSecs =  6001000 ,  processedUSecs =  6000000 
Error State: 0 
platform buffer size after called QAudioInput start(): 1600 
bytesReady =  0 ,  elapsedUSecs =  7005000 ,  processedUSecs =  7000000 
Error State: 0 
platform buffer size after called QAudioInput start(): 1600 
bytesReady =  0 ,  elapsedUSecs =  8002000 ,  processedUSecs =  8000000 
Error State: 0 
platform buffer size after called QAudioInput start(): 1600 
bytesReady =  0 ,  elapsedUSecs =  8997000 ,  processedUSecs =  9000000 
Audio State: 2 
Error State: 0
```

Comment: The out put for the above code retuns as shown:

Comment: try to see an example http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/multimedia-audiorecorder.html

Comment: I think you forget the audio header.

Comment: @Samoth : I have no comopilation errors at all, I have included everythg. I did not show the header files.

Comment: @jeevan_reddy I was not thinking about the c++ headers but this one : [wave header](http://mathmatrix.narod.ru/Wavefmt.html)

Comment: @Samoth - I have no clue on how to use the audio header.I'll be glad if u let me know how to use it in my code. Currently I am creating a file with ".raw" extension, but I tried to create a ".wav" extension too. How should I use the header in my code? I did not see any sample code in Qt projects explaning how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Having compared your code to the example in the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qaudioinput.html), you're using the notified signal to handle the QAudio::ActiveState, whereas the example code connects a slot to the stateChanged signal: -

```
void AudioInputExample::handleStateChanged(QAudio::State newState)
{
    switch (newState) {
        case QAudio::StoppedState:
            if (audio->error() != QAudio::NoError) {
                // Error handling
            } else {
                // Finished recording
            }
            break;

        case QAudio::ActiveState:
            // Started recording - read from IO device
            break;

        default:
            // ... other cases as appropriate
            break;
    }
}
```

As notify() states: -

> This signal is emitted when x ms of audio data has been processed the interval set by setNotifyInterval

Could the interval be zero?

However, I recommend following the example code as shown in the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qaudioinput.html) and use the stateChanged signal, rather than notify.

Comment: The setNotifyInterval by default takes as 1 sec. There is no issue if notify interval is not set. My code perfectly compiles and I'm able to execute it too.

Comment: @jeevan_reddy, I never implied that your code doesn't compile, or that you can't execute it. It sounds like you only read the penultimate two lines of the answer.

Comment: I read your entire comments, my focus is on bytesReady() method of QAudioInput, as far as i know this method should return the audio data read from microphone when in QMedia::ActiveState. I'm noy doing anythg significany when in QActiveState except for printing sme debug statements. The real issue is why is bytesReady() returning 0 when state is Active. I believe this should not happen.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the stateChanged signal, rather than notify?

Comment: I tried it, I was printing the bytesRead() in the slot called when stateChaged signal is emitted. I checked for QAudio::ActiveState and then printed bytesRead() which gives 0.

Comment: Try the audio recorder example and see if that works, or if it's just a general failure of Qt here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/multimedia-audiorecorder.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider PHDEBUG or PHDBG as qDebug() and see the following (I think your missing point is the `QIODevice` which stand as a buffer.):

## Reader.cpp :

```
#include "PhLtcReader.h"

PhLtcReader::PhLtcReader(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    _input(NULL),
    _position(0),
    _buffer(NULL)
{
    _decoder = ltc_decoder_create(1920, 3840);
    PHDEBUG << "LTC Reader created";
}

bool PhLtcReader::init(QString input)
{
    QList<QAudioDeviceInfo> list = QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioInput);

    if(list.isEmpty())
    {
        PHDEBUG << "No audio input device";
        return false;
    }

    QAudioDeviceInfo info = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();

    foreach(QAudioDeviceInfo device, list)
    {
        if(device.deviceName() == input)
            info = device;
    }

    PHDEBUG << "LTC input device :" << info.deviceName();

    QAudioFormat format;
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleRate(48000);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleSize(8);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);

    if(!info.isFormatSupported(format))
    {
        PHDEBUG << "Unsupported audio format";
        return false;
    }

    _position = 0;
    _input = new QAudioInput(info, format);

    connect(_input, SIGNAL(notify()), this, SLOT(onNotify()));
    _buffer = _input->start();
    _input->setNotifyInterval(10);

    _pauseDetector.start();

    return true;
}

void PhLtcReader::close()
{
    if(_input)
    {
        _input->stop();
        delete _buffer;
        _buffer = NULL;
        delete _input;
        _input = NULL;
    }
}

QList<QString> PhLtcReader::inputList()
{
    QList<QString> names;
    QList<QAudioDeviceInfo> list = QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioInput);

    foreach(QAudioDeviceInfo device, list)
        names.append(device.deviceName());

    return names;
}

void PhLtcReader::onNotify()
{

    QByteArray array = _buffer->readAll();
    char max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.count(); i++)
    {
        if(array.at(i) > max)
            max = array.at(i);
    }

    ltc_decoder_write(_decoder, (ltcsnd_sample_t*)array.data(), array.count(), _position);

    LTCFrameExt frame;
    unsigned int *hhmmssff = new unsigned int[4];
    while(ltc_decoder_read(_decoder, &frame))
    {
        PhFrame oldFrame = _clock.frame();
        hhmmssff[0] = frame.ltc.hours_tens * 10 + frame.ltc.hours_units;
        hhmmssff[1] = frame.ltc.mins_tens * 10 + frame.ltc.mins_units;
        hhmmssff[2] = frame.ltc.secs_tens * 10 + frame.ltc.secs_units;
        hhmmssff[3] = frame.ltc.frame_tens * 10 + frame.ltc.frame_units;
    }
    delete hhmmssff;

    _position += array.count();
}
```

## Reader.h

```
class PhLtcReader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit PhLtcReader(QObject *parent = 0);

    bool init(QString _input="");
    void close();

    static QList<QString> inputList();


private slots:
    void onNotify();

private:
    QAudioInput *_input;
    qint64 _position;
    QIODevice * _buffer;
};

#endif // PHLTCREADER_H
```

Comment: The microphone audio is not getting stored in the raw file in the first place. Can smebdy pls let me know how whats the mistake in the above shown code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm unable to record the microphone audio from my desktop and save into the raw file in the first place. I really need help why QAudioInput is not performing its job in the first place. Any help is appreciated. In my case QAudioInput bytesReady() shows 0 even when audio state is Active. QAudioInput is failing to read data from  the desktop's microphone.

Comment: @jeevan_reddy edited my code, try to adapt it then come back ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question can be found in the output.

There is a line that says

`Default format not supported, try to use nearest format`

Which is the problem. The format you're using isn't supported by your platform. Try a different one or install the codecs/drivers to support that format.