# Is there any way in QT to get raw audio data from mic?

Tags: qt, audio, real-time

I am trying to implement a pitch shifter in QT. So I need to get raw data from mic, somehow transform it and play it back. But I can't figure out how to get raw data, send it to buffer and then, when it's transformed, play it back. At the moment I'm doing something like that, but this is working without buffer and I can't change data that is going to be played.

```
QAudioFormat format;
format.setSampleRate(96000);
format.setChannelCount(1);
format.setSampleSize(32);
format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

audio = new QAudioInput(format, this);
connect(audio, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), this, SLOT(handleStateChanged(QAudio::State)));

QIODevice* device = audio->start();
connect(device,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(process()));


QAudioOutput* output = new QAudioOutput(format, this);
output->start(device);
```

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to do this real-time?  Otherwise, why not just write to a file, process the file and then send it to QAudioOutput?

If you are trying to convert "on the fly" you may have to chain a QBuffer and maybe a QQueue, but there would be lots of conversions involved. as QBuffer and QQueue are byte oriented.  Grab the underlying data pointer and do the pointer arithmetic the handle as short I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `QAudio` class worth looking into.

Other options that come to mind are `QIODevice` with `QDataStream`.

[This post may get you headed in the right direction.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429838/unable-to-record-audio-from-microphone-to-qfile-in-qt)

Answer (score 0):

I think the classes you're looking for are `QAudioInput` and `QAudioOutput`, both part of the Qt Multimedia module.

`QAudioInput` offers the ability to get a byte stream from the microphone, which you can use for whatever you need. Once you apply whatever transformations you need, you can push it to speakers using `QAudioOutput`. Both offer a few different settings relating to the buffer size, sample frequency, etc that you can play with to fit your specific needs.

Here are some links you may find useful:

[Qt Audio Overview](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/audiooverview.html)

[QAudioInput documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudioinput.html)

[QAudioOutput documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiooutput.html)

Comment: I forgot to add the code I'm using. I've actually using QAudioInput, but I can't figure out how to get raw data, process it and then send it to QAudioOutput.

Comment: This answer didn't really enlighten me with anything I didn't already find.